# What is the best practice for nifi production deployment

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a three node nifi cluster. We just installed nifi packages on linux machines and cluster with separate zookeeper cluster. I am planning to monitor nifi performance via nagios but we saw hortonworks ambari provides fetures for management and monitoring also.

What is the best practice for nifi deployment on prod

- how should we scale up
- how can we monitor nifi
- Should we monitor queue/process performance
- Should use something like ambari

regards..

---

Edit-1: 
@James actually I am collecting user event logs from several sources within company.

All events are first written to Kafka. Nifi consumes kafka, does simple transformations like getting a field from payload to attribute.

After transformations data is written to both elasticsearch and hdfs. Before writing to hdfs we are merging flowfiles so writing to hdfs is in batches.

I have around 50k/s event.

Comment: This is a very broad topic.  Apache NiFi optimization depends a great deal on the nature of your business problem, data, connecting systems, and team working on it.  Can you provide some more focus?

Comment: @James I edit the question. fyi.

Comment: I would love to learn more on production deployment issues of NiFi